# Fetch Uint16 from readable stream

Tags: javascript, random, uint16

In the following example I'm fetching 2 raw bytes.

```
fetch('https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=2')
    .then(response=>response.body.getReader())
    .then(reader=>0/*Here convert to Uint16*/)
```

Any idea how to convert the resulting readable stream  Uint16 integer from using 2 bytes?

Comment: Once you [got the reader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/getReader), just [`read()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader/read) from it?

Comment: Btw, it's probably much easier to read the response body [into an array buffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer) than to use a readable stream reader.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you get all needed bytes in the first chunk, then you can try this:

```js
fetch('https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=2')
    .then(response=>response.body.getReader())
    .then(reader => reader.read())
    .then(result => console.log(new DataView(result.value.buffer).getUint16()));
```

See [`ReadableStreamDefaultReader.read()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStreamDefaultReader/read), [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array), and [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView).

Or a simpler way:

```js
fetch('https://www.random.org/cgi-bin/randbyte?nbytes=2')
    .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(buffer => console.log(new DataView(buffer).getUint16()));
```